# Encrypted S/MIME E-Mail with un-encrypted part possible?

Tags: email, encryption, cryptography, mime, smime

I would like to know whether it is technically possible to created an S/MIME-*encrypted* E-Mail that also contains un-encrypted part. The idea is that the user would see the un-encrypted part, if and only if the message could not be decrypted (e.g. missing private key). Otherwise, if the message *can* be decrypted, the encrypted part will be displayed to the user as always.

A possible solution would be to wrap the whole S/MIME structure into a "multipart/alternative" MIME structure. One part would be "text/plain" containing some info text, the other part would be "application/pkcs7-mime" containing the actual (encrypted) payload.

However, I cannot find any information on whether S/MIME does allow this. Also it would be important to know if standard Mail-Clients can handle such construct in the intended way.

Thanks in advance for any information!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MIME allows this. Whether you'll find any mail clients that support *sending* it is a completely separate matter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. _Sending_ is **not ** that much of a problem, because it will be an auto-generated message, which means sending happens on server-side (in Java code). The bigger problem, I think, is whether standard mail-clients (Outlook, Thunderbrid, Android, iOS) will be able to display this construct...